# Why this won't let me migrate on production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to use the gem called [acts_as_commentable_with_threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading).
As the document says, I executed these below

```
rails generate acts_as_commentable_with_threading_migration

rake db:migrate ENV=production
```

However this only add comments table into development database but not into production database:(

Why and how can I add comments table to production database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: smart answer! That was it! my bad. I'll make this as a correct answer within 11min!! thanks!